# IBM Mobilefirst 7.1 - Java HTTP Adapter Calling

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am using Mobilefirst 7.1 to develop a Java HTTP Adapter for my Angular 2 hybrid project to call.

## What I have done:

1) Built the Java Adapter that has a few POST & GET procedures

2) Deployed into my local MobileFirst Operations Console

## What I want to achieve:

1) Using Angular 2 HTTP requests, call to adapter endpoints and get response successfully

2) No MFP sdk or MFP app will be used

## My testing (in  Postman Rest Client):

1) **[SUCCESS]** Get test token from test token endpoint, add '**Authorization**' header in adapter requests, call adapter endpoint and get response successfully : [Test in postman](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/server-side-development/java-adapter/#in-postman)

2) **[SUCCESS]** Java Adapter disabled security (**@OAuthSecurity(enabled=false)**), *without* test token & *without* 'Authorization' header, call adapter endpoint and get response successfully

3) **[FAILED]** When Java Adapter set security **annotation @OAuthSecurity(scope="adminRealm")**, calling adapter endpoint will get missing_authorization / insufficient_scope in below scenarios

- Getting testtoken & set 'Authorization' header similar to test 1
- Without test token & without setting 'Authorization' header similar to test 2

## My questions

1) Based on my understanding, in actual production, test token should not be used in calling adapter endpoint. Hence if Java Adapter has default security enabled, how to call in Postman successfully without that test token?

2) How do I call the adapter endpoint successfully using Angular 2 HTTP requests? I do not encounter this problem in calling normal REST endpoint using Angular 2 HTTP.

3) Do I need another endpoint to get access token in actual production, instead of that test token endpoint?

Comment: By the way someone wrote a blog post integration ionic2 with mfp: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/10/17/integrating-mobilefirst-foundation-8-in-ionic2-based-apps/

Comment: I just realized you wrote you use 7.1, the link I provided was for 8.0 (which I recommended upgrading to). But here is a link for 7.1: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/08/14/going-forward/

Comment: Thanks for the link, will look into it :)

Answer (score 0):

The **test token** that you mentioned is nothing more than a [confident client](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/authentication-and-security/confidential-clients/) token.

I am not familiar with your use case, but confidential clients are not meant to be used in customer-facing client applications. They are usually meant for server-side applications that need to access a MobileFirst resource. A confidential client will *skip* all the security you configured.

Customer-facing client applications are supposed to use the MFP client SDKs, and implement challenge handlers.

Now let's assume you really have a good reason to use confidential clients in your application (please share that good reason), follow the instructions in the [confidential client tutorial](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/authentication-and-security/confidential-clients/) to create a confidential client with exactly the scope you want it to have.

For example, create a confidential client named `myAngularApp` with a scope of `adminRealm`. Now any client with a valid `myAngularApp` token will have access to resources protected by `adminRealm`.

One thing was not clear in your testing. What is the difference between test (1) and test (3)? In both of them you wrote that you call the adapter endpoint.

Comment: More informatin: 
currently my client app is an Cordova Angular 2 app so there are no confidential client or scope, while my MFP java adapter is using default security settings (my understanding is if there are no OAuthSecurity annotation declared, the adapter will have default security setting, is this correct?). 
So is there any way my app able to call to the adapter without using any MFP sdk or Cordova MFP plugin? Meaning using Angular HTTP request.

Comment: "so there are no confidential client or scope" - not sure what you mean - confidential client and scope are things you configure in the server, it does not matter what the client is. You are correct that if there is no annotation it uses the default security, however "default" security does not mean NO security. You still need a valid token (which the MFP client SDK does for you).

Comment: So can I confirm that with 'default' security, there is no way to use angular 2 HTTP request to call the adapter?

Comment: There are ways, it's called "do it yourself" and involves deeply understanding the entire flow. It's not recommended. You would basically be mimicking what the MFP client SDK does.

Comment: Alright, appreciate the replies. Last ques: are there any online sources available on this if I would like to perform above use case? Because the only documentation/flow that I can get is from the MFP site https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/all-tutorials/
which I can't find any related information on this

Comment: What do you mean by above use case? The tutorials all assume that you are using the MFP SDK, in which case you are not doing anything special just follow the basic tutorials. If you are talking about "do it yourself", no tutorial on that, it's not recommended - even more Donnie that I noticed you use MFP 7.1